# My calendar notes before November 2022 do not appear. I had saved all the health and important information of my children like a diary

Tags: calendar, cloud

My calendar notes before November 2022 do not appear. I had saved all the health notes and important information of my family and children in the calendar and search back very often. There was no problem and all the notes were visible, but now it is empty. I need to access my past information. How can I see calendar notes when I go back to previous years as before? This is very important to me, I need someone's support.

I want to see my previous calender notes

Comment: Please add some information about what calendar software you are using and how it is configured. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you in a concrete way. Btw., my first assumption would be that there is kind of an "auto-delete old entries" function active.